# Format double value in c++

Tags: c++

I have a double value and I want to limit precision of it and then convert to string.

```
double dblValue = 50.0000018963;
```

I need to convert this to, 50.0 and to string format.

Comment: Step 1: [`std::round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) Step 2: [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) Step 3: ???? Step 4: Profit!

Comment: Look for `std::setprecision()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++ you can use std::stringstream and precision property:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    double d = 50.0123456789;
    std::string s;
    std::stringstream sstream;
    sstream.setf(std::ios::fixed);
    sstream.precision(1);
    sstream << d;

    s = sstream.str();
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note, that precision inherited from std::ios_base, so std::cout has it too. If you simply want output this value, you can set `std::cout.precision()` to 1.

Also you can find more about this on 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/ and
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the docs of [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

`sprtintf(yourchararrayORstring, "%.2f", dblValue);`

**Note: This will only write the double with 2 precision points to string and not round or modify you `dblValue`**

or as suggested by Cory

Step 1: `std::round` Step 2: `std::to_string` Step 3: ???? Step 4: Profit!